# Class 'String' has no instance method '-'

Tags: dart

What method instead of method '-' in String type?
I want to remove an element of 'ngang'. This is data of 'ngang':

```
String ngang ='';
for (int i =0; i <x; i++){
ngang +='*';}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like `ngang` is a `String`. String does not have a `-` (minus) operator in Dart. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please add some more details to the question. Why are you subtracting "1" from a String? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, so I try the other way. Can you help me?

Comment: @ThịLê We can properly help you but we don't understand what you are trying to do. Please explain in details what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to remove an element of 'ngang'?

Comment: @ThịLê What do you mean by `an element` here? It is a `String`. Do you mean a letter? If yes, what letter? The first or the last? Please. We need details! :)

Comment: I want to remove an element of 'ngang'. This is data of 'ngang':

String ngang ='';
for (int i =0; i <x; i++){
ngang +='*';}

Comment: @ThịLê That is really an awful way to construct a `String` in Dart...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on latest update of the question, the question is how to remove the last letter of a `String` which can be done like this:

```
ngang = ngang.substring(0, ngang.length - 1);
```

I also want to add that this code:

```
  String ngang = '';
  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    ngang += '*';
  }
```

Is a really inefficient way to create a `String`. You could instead use the `*` operator on `String` or use a `StringBuffer`:

```
String ngang = '*' * x;
```

If you really want, you can introduce your own extension method which provides the `-` (minus) operator on `String` and does what you are expecting it to do:

```
void main() {
  const x = 5;
  String ngang = '*' * x;
  print(ngang); // *****
  ngang -= 1;
  print(ngang); // ****
}

extension MinusOperatorOnString on String {
  String operator -(int removeFromEnd) => substring(0, length - removeFromEnd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what does 0 mean?

Comment: @ThịLê Please read the documentation for `substring`: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/String/substring.html . `0` means here the start of the `String`. We are creating a new string where we take all letters from the existing one except from the last one.

Comment: @ThịLê Updated my answer with an extension method solution which makes it possible to use `String` as you are trying to do. You can read more about extension methods here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods

Comment: Can you give me your fb? I want to exchange code with you

Comment: If you don't have further questions and you think my solution works, please accept my answer.

Comment: I sent mess to your mail. Please check :)

Comment: @ThịLê I also sent you a message.